# How to store new objects in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML Page:-

```
<div class="form-group">  
  <label>Template:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.Template">

  <label class="col-md-6">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.Name">

    <label class="col-md-6">Class:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.Class">

    <label class="col-md-4">Code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.Code">
    <label class="col-md-4">Item Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.ItemName">
</div>


             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Template</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Class</th>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Item Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="row in List track by $index">
                                <td>{{row.Template}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.Name}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.Class}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.Code}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.Item Name}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                  </table> 



 <button type="submit" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

In my directive Page:-

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.components')
        .directive('info', info);

    info.$inject = ['$http' , '$timeout' ];

    function info($http, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {

            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                scope.a = {};
                scope.List = [];

             scope.add = function () {
               scope.List.push(scope.newBsb);

            };

            },
            templateUrl: ''
        };
    }

})();
```

What I am trying to do is on my 'add' button all the information user inputs should be added in the List array. I am storing the user input in an object 'a'.
What should I do so every object should be added in the array.

Comment: Show your `add` button functionality and what the directive is for?

Comment: I support @SaiUnique. need more code and clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your button:

```
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

This should suffice for your function add:

```
 function add() {
   List.push([$scope.a]);
 }
```